# C# array byte[].Length property

Tags: c#, arrays

C# array byte[].Length property.

byte[] buffer = new ...

When call int i = buffer.Length; I can see get_Length() in reflector,

What happens? Does it calculate actual length or just takes value (like property) ???

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx

Comment: `get_Length()` is just part of how .NET implements the getter on the `Length` property.

Comment: Why did you edit your question to delete most of it? It's now impossible to understand what the question is.

Comment: it's not me. my account was hacked

Comment: Question restored

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`byte[].Length` will tell you the total number of elements in the [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), so retrieving this property has a complexity of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays are fixed-length; the `Length` property returns an internal field in the array.
(It's `O(1)`, not `O(n)`)